# Mapping AD Domain users to Linux Users Issue

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I have setup a RHEL5 server that is running samba & winbind.  I am also using the 'username map' feature to map all my Linux user accounts to their AD user accounts.  The Windows users can map to the Samba share and everything works as it should.

The only issue I am having is when the Windows users are coping files to the share the files are set with the AD User account of 'DOMAIN+user' instead of the Linux user 'user group'.

Does anyone know of a way that when the Windows users add files to the share that the permissions with be for their Linux account and not their AD user account?    Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it the way that you're configuring it, but I know that Likewise Open did all of this for me. It makes it extremely easy to add domain users into local groups, and UID/GIDs are a hash, so they're identical across all of my authenticated machines. I can't tell you how amazing it was to finally have it just work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how *username map* works...

Could you give the linux user accounts the same uid as the DOMAIN+user equivalent?  In that case when you log on as the linux user, you will be able to see the same files that the DOMAIN+user can.

Comment: I would need to change all my Linux user ID's to 'DOMAIN+user' so they map correctly but I have a few users who do not want to change their ID's.  Even my user ID which is the same on the Linux servers an in AD has an issue with files that I add to these Linux servers from my Windows boxes.  So if I logon to the Linux servers I would have to 'chown' all the files so that they are owned by the Linux user account and not the 'DOMAIN.user' account.

Comment: If you still need to chown the files (and it works to do that), then I have not been clear.  Making your linux UID match the UID listed when you do "getent passwd|grep DOMAIN+user" means that chown will not do anything.  The UID will already be the same.